# Flutter streambuilder has no data in release mode

Tags: flutter, firebase

My application for some reason isn't working correctly on profile/release version.

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('1');
    final userData = context.watch<UserModel>();
    return StreamBuilder<List<AppointmentModel>>(
        stream: widget._eventStream as Stream<List<AppointmentModel>>,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print('2');
          if (!snapshot.hasData) return const CircularProgressIndicator();
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print('3');
            final events = snapshot.data;
```

Basically the snapshot has no data in profile/release mode but in debug mode it's fine. Profile mode returns 1 and 2 only and I keep seeing CircularProgressIndicator.
While debug mode returns 1-2-3 and correct data. Anyone know what could be the cause?

Answer (score 1):

Please provide more information:

1. how does `widget._eventStream` gets the data?
2. Could you confirm that on both platforms (iOS and Android) on profile/release modes, you have the problem?

First, I can guess that you get data for the stream from some backed over HTTP or WebSocket.
Second, if the problem is only on Android, make sure that in the `AppManifest.xml` files under `/android/app/src/profile` and `/android/app/src/main`, you have the next line of code for permission:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: widget._eventStream gets data from Firebase. It is fine i think because in Debug mode it sucessfuly gets the data.
Here are my permissions
```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```
Also my app is Android only.